# MS ACCESS: I need to add a suffix to duplicate values on my table

Tags: ms-access

I want to add suffix to all duplicate fields on my table.

Ex.

Table 1

abcde

abcde

abcde

fghij

fghij

klmno

Expected Result

Table 1

abcde(1)

abcde(2)

abcde(3)

fghij(1)

fghij(2)

klmno

Any idea how I can accomplish this task using MS ACCESS???
Thank you.

Comment: MS Access doesn't support a `ROW_NUMBER()` function.  Do you have any sort of ID column in your table?

Comment: Hi sir, I'm afraid there's none. Just need to make them unique that's why I want to add suffix.

Comment: You can't do this in Access as far as I know, because Access itself has no way of distinguishing these duplicates.  You should rethink your table design.

Comment: Wait a minute...didn't you ask this same question yesterday?

Comment: thanks a lot for the inputs sir.

Comment: i assume you don't have much programming experience, but surely you can do this some vba code.

Comment: @O.Gungor yeah i don't have that much experience. hope you can help me doing it in VBA. thanks,

Comment: You can't have "duplicated fields" in Access - or any other database for that matter - so please rephrase your question.

Comment: Can't you just add an autonumber field?

Answer (score 0):

First select the duplicates, rather than looping though the entire table.  Then append a suffix to the duplicates.
...you need to add a ID/AutoNumber field to your table so that each individual duplicate can be targeted.

```
Dim dbs As Database
Dim rstDuplicates As Recordset
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim n As Integer
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rstDuplicates = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblRenameDuplicates.f_FieldName FROM tblRenameDuplicates GROUP BY tblRenameDuplicates.f_FieldName HAVING Count(f_FieldName)>1;")
rstDuplicates.MoveLast
rstDuplicates.MoveFirst
If Not rstDuplicates.EOF Then
    Do While Not rstDuplicates.EOF
        Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblRenameDuplicates WHERE tblRenameDuplicates.f_FieldName = '" & rstDuplicates!f_FieldName & "';")
        rst.MoveLast
        rst.MoveFirst
        n = 1
        Do While Not rst.EOF
            DoCmd.RunSQL ("UPDATE tblRenameDuplicates SET f_FieldName = '" & rst!f_FieldName.Value & n & "' WHERE f_FieldID = " & rst!f_fieldID & ";")
            n = n + 1
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop
        rstDuplicates.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
rst.Close
rstDuplicates.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set rstDuplicates = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing
```

OR, if no ID/AutoNumber field can be added to the table:

```
        Do While Not rst.EOF
            rst.Edit
            rst!f_fieldname = rst!f_fieldname & n
            rst.Update
            n = n + 1
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop
```

Comment: can you do it in ms access?